# JavaScript adding two numbers, adding vs concatenate, FCC Golf Code Challenge

Tags: javascript, concatenation

I've been struggling to figure out why my If Else statement is returning incorrectly with any value after Par. I believe it's because my If Else is attempting to concatenate instead of add, but I can't figure out how to fix it. Thanks! http://codepen.io/SalvatoreSantamaria/pen/XNGNqZ

```js
function x(par, strokes) {

  if (strokes == 1) {
    return "Hole-in-one!";
  } else if (strokes <= par - 2) {
    return "Eagle";
  } else if (strokes == par - 1) {
    return "Birdie";
  } else if (strokes == par) {
    return "Par";
  } else if (strokes == par + 1) {
    return "Bogey";
  } else if (strokes == par + 2) {
    return "Double Bogey";
  } else if (strokes >= par + 3) {
    return "Go Home!";
  }
}

document.getElementById("submitText").addEventListener("click", function() {
  input = document.getElementById("inputText").value;
  input2 = document.getElementById("inputText2").value;
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = x(input, input2);
});
```

```html
</br>
Input Par
<input type="number" id="inputText" />
</br>
Input Strokes
<input type="number" id="inputText2" />
</br>
<input type="Submit" id="submitText" value="Submit" </input>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Where do you guys learn to use `</br>`. There's nothing like that!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually very simple. ALL values taken from form elements (input elements in your case) are strings, not numbers.

In order to do math with them, you must first convert them to numbers.

Modify your line to use the **[`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)** JavaScript function:

```
x(parseInt(input,10), parseInt(input2,10));
```

A better way to structure your code would be to not store the values of the input elements, but to store references to the elements themselves. That way you can keep referencing the objects over and over without having to scan for them over and over.

```
input = document.getElementById("inputText");
input2 = document.getElementById("inputText2");

var input1Num = parseInt(input.value, 10);
var input2Num = parseInt(input2.value, 10);
x(input1Num, input2Num);
```

**Finally, as others have pointed out, some of your HTML is incorrect as you have markup like this:**

```
</br>
```

and

```
<input type="Submit" id="submitText" value="Submit" </input>
```

Both of these errors are rooted in the misunderstanding of what elements must be terminated and what elements may not be explicitly terminated with a closing tag. Along with this is the (legal but largely irrelevant these days) syntax of "self-terminating" elements, which is a form of syntax that is used in a variant of HTML called XHTML. While this syntax is legal in HTML5, I highly discourage its use. For details on why, read my post **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41247247/page-content-not-displayed-with-self-terminating-tag/41247288#41247288)**.

So finally, a finished version of the code would be:

```js
// Get references to the DOM elements you'll need (not properties of the objects)
var input1 = document.getElementById("inputText1");
var input2 = document.getElementById("inputText2");
var output = document.getElementById("output");
var btn = document.getElementById("submitText");

// Wire up the button to run your function when it's clicked
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  // Only get the input values when you need to run your function
  var input1Num = parseInt(input1.value, 10);
  var input2Num = parseInt(input2.value, 10);

  // Call the function and pass it the values it needs
  output.textContent = x(input1Num, input2Num);
});
    

function x(par, strokes) {

  // You are going to return a string no matter what
  var result = "";
  
  if (strokes == 1) {
    result = "Hole-in-one!";
  } else if (strokes <= par - 2) {
    result = "Eagle";
  } else if (strokes == par - 1) {
    result = "Birdie";
  } else if (strokes == par) {
    result = "Par";
  } else if (strokes == par + 1) {
    result = "Bogey";
  } else if (strokes == par + 2) {
    result = "Double Bogey";
  } else if (strokes >= par + 3) {
    result = "Go Home!";
  }
  
  // Now just return once:
  return result;
}
```

```html
<br>
Input Par
<input type="number" id="inputText1">
<br>
Input Strokes
<input type="number" id="inputText2">
<br>
<!-- Just use a regular button here, since you aren't actually
     submitting any form data anywhere -->
<input type="button" id="submitText" value="Submit">
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you for taking the time to explain everything!

Answer (score 2):

If the values should be integers you should convert the strings (you get from the `document.getElementById("inputText").value`) to int, using the [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function:

```js
function x(par, strokes) {

  if (strokes == 1) {
    return "Hole-in-one!";
  } else if (strokes <= par - 2) {
    return "Eagle";
  } else if (strokes == par - 1) {
    return "Birdie";
  } else if (strokes == par) {
    return "Par";
  } else if (strokes == par + 1) {
    return "Bogey";
  } else if (strokes == par + 2) {
    return "Double Bogey";
  } else if (strokes >= par + 3) {
    return "Go Home!";
  }
}

document.getElementById("submitText").addEventListener("click", function() {
  input = parseInt(document.getElementById("inputText").value);
  input2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("inputText2").value);
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = x(input, input2);
});
```

```html
<br />
Input Par
<input type="number" id="inputText" />
<br />
Input Strokes
<input type="number" id="inputText2" />
<br />
<input type="Submit" id="submitText" value="Submit" />
<div id="output"></div>
```

Also note that you had HTML issues. I fixed them in this example.

Comment: Mate, did you even check the HTML?

Comment: @PraveenKumar, You are right! there were html errors there. But the main issue was the problems with the int/string values :) (anyway - code updated)

Comment: btw, @PraveenKumar , a voteup on my answer will be nice, as it was the first answer here who mentioned the **real** problem - the parseInt :) You added it to your answer afterwards.

Comment: Thank you so much! :) I'm still learning HTML and JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

There are way too many issues with your code.

1. There's no `</br>`. Replace it with `<br />`.
2. There's no `</input>`. Replace it correctly according to the below snippet.
3. Convert string to integer using `parseInt()`.

You need to learn HTML correctly to get the right output:

```js
function x(par, strokes) {
  par = parseInt(par);
  strokes = parseInt(strokes);
  if (strokes == 1) {
    return "Hole-in-one!";
  } else if (strokes <= par - 2) {
    return "Eagle";
  } else if (strokes == par - 1) {
    return "Birdie";
  } else if (strokes == par) {
    return "Par";
  } else if (strokes == par + 1) {
    return "Bogey";
  } else if (strokes == par + 2) {
    return "Double Bogey";
  } else if (strokes >= par + 3) {
    return "Go Home!";
  }
}

document.getElementById("submitText").addEventListener("click", function() {
  input = document.getElementById("inputText").value;
  input2 = document.getElementById("inputText2").value;
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = x(input, input2);
});
```

```html
Input Par
<input type="number" id="inputText" />
<br />Input Strokes
<input type="number" id="inputText2" />
<br />
<input type="Submit" id="submitText" value="Submit" />
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you can have `<br>` or `<br />`, but not `</br>`. Yet, more examples of how XHTML causes more problems than it solves. Merry Christmas! ;)

Comment: @ScottMarcus Ha ha.. Welcome back. Sure. You could say XHTML is a double edged sword.

Answer (score 2):

An addition to [Praveen Kumar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41315530/1447675):

You could use the return literately and go on without else.

```js
function x(par, strokes) {
    if (strokes == 1) {
        return "Hole-in-one!";
    }
    if (strokes <= par - 2) {
        return "Eagle";
    }
    if (strokes == par - 1) {
        return "Birdie";
    }
    if (strokes == par) {
        return "Par";
    }
    if (strokes == par + 1) {
        return "Bogey";
    }
    if (strokes == par + 2) {
        return "Double Bogey";
    }
    if (strokes >= par + 3) {
        return "Go Home!";
    }
}

document.getElementById("submitText").addEventListener("click", function() {
    input = +document.getElementById("inputText").value;   // use Number
    input2 = +document.getElementById("inputText2").value; // use Number
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = x(input, input2);
});
```

```html
Input Par
<input type="number" id="inputText" />
<br />Input Strokes
<input type="number" id="inputText2" />
<br />
<input type="Submit" id="submitText" value="Submit" />
<div id="output"></div>
```

A more concise style could be the use of an object with a check for `"Hole-in-one!"` or with the delta of `strokes - par`, with a default value.

```js
function x(par, strokes) {
    var delta = {
        'true': "Hole-in-one!",
        '-2': "Eagle",
        '-1': "Birdie",
        '0': "Par",
        '1': "Bogey",
        '2': "Double Bogey",
        '3': "Go Home!"
    };
    return delta[strokes == 1 || strokes - par] || delta[3];
}

document.getElementById("submitText").addEventListener("click", function() {
    input = +document.getElementById("inputText").value;   // use Number
    input2 = +document.getElementById("inputText2").value; // use Number
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = x(input, input2);
});
```

```html
Input Par
<input type="number" id="inputText" />
<br />Input Strokes
<input type="number" id="inputText2" />
<br />
<input type="Submit" id="submitText" value="Submit" />
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Ha ha... True that... `:)`

Comment: It would be much cleaner to set up a string variable and set the return string in the `if` branches and then just return that string after all the `if` statements. Nothing good has ever come from multiple `returns`. ;)

Comment: @ScottMarcus, it follows the style *return early*, *return often*.

Comment: That style is meant so that you can avoid `else` branches. It's not explicitly stating that multiple `return`s are necessarily good. In this case, you can avoid all the `else` and the `return` with a simple string variable.  In programming in general, excessive branching code is a bad thing. It harkens back to the infamous `goto`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, please see proposal with an object.